# Using XPath in SelectSingleNode: Retrieving individual element from XML if it's present

Tags: c#, xpath, selectsinglenode

My XML looks like :

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<itemSet>
       <Item>one</Item>
       <Item>two</Item>
       <Item>three</Item>
       .....maybe more Items here.
</itemSet>
```

Some of the individual **Item** may or may not be present. Say I want to retrieve the element *`<Item>`**two**`</Item>`* if it's present. I've tried the following XPaths (in C#).

- `XMLNode node = myXMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("/itemSet[Item='two']")` --- If  Item *two* is present, then it returns me only the first element *one*. Maybe this query just points to the first element in itemSet, if it has an Item of value two somewhere as a child. Is this interpretation correct?

So I tried:

- `XMLNode node = myXMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("/itemSet[Item='two']/Item[1]")` --- I read this query as, return me the first *`<Item>`* element within itemSet that has value = 'two'. Am I correct?

This still returns only the first element *one*. What am I doing wrong? 
In both the cases, using the siblings I can traverse the child nodes and get to *two*, but that's not what I am looking at. Also if two is absent then SelectSingleNode returns null. Thus the very fact that I am getting a successfull return node does indicate the presence of element two, so had I wanted a boolean test to chk presence of *two*, any of the above XPaths would suffice, but I actually the need the full element *`<Item>two</Item>`* as my return node.

*[My first question here, and my first time working with web programming, so I just learned the above XPaths and related xml stuff on the fly right now from past questions in SO. So be gentle, and let me know if I am a doofus or flouting any community rules. Thanks.]*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you want:

```
myXMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("/itemSet/Item[text()='two']")
```

In other words, you want the *Item* which has text of two, not the `itemSet` containing it.

You can also use a single dot to indicate the context node, in your case:

```
myXMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("/itemSet/Item[.='two']")
```

EDIT: The difference between `.` and `text()` is that `.` means "this node" effectively, and `text()` means "all the text node children of this node". In both cases the comparison will be against the "string-value" of the LHS. For an element node, the string-value is "the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order" and for a collection of text nodes, the comparison will check whether any text node is equal to the one you're testing against.

So it doesn't matter when the element content only has a single text node, but suppose we had:

```
<root>
  <item name="first">x<foo/>y</item>
  <item name="second">xy<foo/>ab</item>
</root>
```

Then an XPath expression of "`root/item[.='xy']`" will match the first item, but "`root/item[text()='xy']`" will match the second.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jon. Both your solutions worked like a charm. While on topic, can I ask, what's the difference between using text() and .? In my sample XML it's a simple element with just one text value, so both solutions return the same thing. Is there a complicated XML situation where one is preferred over the other or results are different?

(Other than marking yr ans correct and voting up, is there anything SO communitywise I can do to thank you?)

Comment: @areaMan: To be honest, I'm not sure of the difference between "text()" and ".". My XPath-fu is fairly minimal :) You might want to look at the XPath specs to find out more: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath

As for what you can do to thank me... find a question you can answer, and answer it as well as you can. Oh, and keep asking good questions :)

Comment: Having said that about not knowing the difference, I know *some* of the differences between . and text() - will edit.