# htmlagilitypack using SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, selectsinglenode

I've been trying to get the value of  below using HtmlAgilityPack but without success. I'm using SelectSingleNode.

Here is my html.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>One</td></tr>       
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is the codebehind.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\test.html");

HtmlNode test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td");
Console.WriteLine(test.InnerHtml);
```

The `test` (HtmlNode) variable is null.

How am I going to get the value inside  which is `One`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown your sample *does not* have `tbody` node so your XPath would return no nodes (`null` for `SelectSingleNode`).

Fix:

```
HtmlNode test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/table/tr/td");
```

Debugging tip: build XPath slowly and check each result/child nodes:

```
     "/html/body/table/" - some children
     "/html/body/table/tbody/"  - null
     "/html/body/table/tr/" - some children
     "/html/body/table/tr/td" - score
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I know that there is no tbody but when I used Chrome's developer tool (F12) then copy the xpath of the elemen (right click), the xpath includes the tbody text.

Answer (score 1):

From [Using XPath in SelectSingleNode: Retrieving individual element from XML if it's present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883698/using-xpath-in-selectsinglenode-retrieving-individual-element-from-xml-if-its) you need to use `text()`:

```
var test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/table/tr/td/text()");
```

Also, you need to remove `tbody`.  There is no `tbody` in your html.

Comment: Why do you expect child node (text) to exist when parent could not be found?

Comment: Good point.  Just noticed the original xpath is reference a `tbody` node that doesn't exist.

Comment: +1: for actual answer (`tbody` not present in sample). Note that `text()` is absolutely not related to the issue and not needed (unless actually looking for text nodes inside "td", which is not what OP's sample shows - InnerHtml includes all nodes too - also the same for particular sample)

Comment: Thanks also for replying to my question. I replied to Alexei's answer above the reason why there is tbody in my xpath. 

I know that there is no tbody but when I used Chrome's developer tool (F12) then copy the xpath of the elemen (right click), the xpath includes the tbody text.